# android determine if activity context or application context

Tags: android

I have an **async task** that makes an upload and shows a **progress dialog**. I would like to be able to not show the dialog if it is being called by a service and thus can't show a dialog. The problem is there a way to **determine which type of context** i have(an activity or an application) ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 if( context instanceof Activity ) {
    //...
 } else {
    //...
 }
```

Comment: ofcourse, i had forgotten about using this in another part of my code, thanks

Comment: Just checking, does this hold true for any subclasses/types of Activity, such as AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity? It appears so from my testing.